# Why does my database only update successfully on first two jsp form submissions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, oracle11g

OK so I have a jsp that features input boxes where a user can insert integers. My Java servlet class then gets these integers, adds them to their corresponding values currently in the database and then divides the total by the formSubmissionCount to get an average figure. Everything works fine the first and second time the same user submits their stats but on the third occasion (and each time thereafter) the stats don't calculate the correct figure (the new value submitted to the database simply decreases each time). I'm not sure why this is happening, here is my logic in my doPost():

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    // 1. GET SUBMITTED JSP FORM VALUES
    String roundScore = req.getParameter("score_avg").toString();
    double roundScoreDouble = Double.parseDouble(roundScore);
    String roundPutts = req.getParameter("putts").toString();
    double puttsDouble = Double.parseDouble(roundPutts);*/
    // 2. GET LOGGED IN USER DETAILS
    Session session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBean.class);
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    String userLoggedIn = authentication.getName();
    List<UserBean> retrievedUser = criteria.add(
            Restrictions.like("username", userLoggedIn)).list();
    // 3. CREATE NEW UPDATED VALUES
    for (UserBean string : retrievedUser) {
        double calculateSubmitCount = string.getSubmitCount() + 1;
        double addRoundScoreValues = roundScoreDouble
                + string.getScore_avg();
        double newRoundScore = addRoundScoreValues / calculateSubmitCount;
        double truncatedRoundScore = new BigDecimal(newRoundScore)
                .setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        string.setScore_avg(truncatedRoundScore);
        double addPuttsValues = puttsDouble + string.getPutts();
        double newPuttsTotal = addPuttsValues / calculateSubmitCount;
        double truncatedPutts = new BigDecimal(newPuttsTotal)
        .setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();               
        string.setPutts(truncatedPutts);
        string.setSubmitCount(string.getSubmitCount() + 1);
        ManagedSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory());
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    if (session.getTransaction().wasRolledBack()) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/error.jsp").forward(req,
                resp);
    } else {
        session.close();
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsps/analysisoutcome.jsp")
                .forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note on code quality: if you just put together this code to show all the things that happen for "doPost", then fine. Otherwise: seriously consider refactoring your code; sorry to say that: but right now, this code is "dirty" all over the place ( see http://www.tud.ttu.ee/im/Kaarel.Allik/JOOP/Clean_Code_-_A_Handbook_of_Agile_Software_Craftsmanship.pdf ; if you want to do it "better")

Comment: I appreciate your point yes my code could be a lot better but this comes with experience and right now I'm just starting out and trying to get things working

Comment: I tend to disagree. Writing **good** code is a very special skill that needs specific practice. In my opinion, one should not start with "I want to learn how to just get xyz running"; and then much later start with "Now, I want to understand how to write programs that are easy to read, maintain and extend". In other words: if time allows, one should read corresponding books (like the one I linked too) very early. Why getting used to bad practices first; and then spend time on getting rid of them later on. It seems more efficient to learn the good practices right from day one.

Comment: you should work with BigDecimal from the beginning if you make operations

Comment: Yes that's true I have now changed from Double's to BigDecimal's I just hadn't changed them since I had to change the data types in the Oracle instance also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my logic not with data types. I needed to multiply the current average score in the database by the current submission count value, then add this value to the new value the user has input and lastly divide this sum by the value of the submission count added to one.